# Making a html javascript pre-programmed console (if input == example) { print no example for you }

Tags: javascript, html, console

how to make a own javascript console...
 (if input == example) { print no example for you }

or 
if form input == then javascript prints text

Template :

```
<div class="main">

<p id="result"></p>

<textarea cols="40" id="SearchText" rows="1"></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Submit!</button>

</div>
```

Script :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var result = document.getElementById("SearchText").value == hi;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'hello';

if  (document.getElementById("SearchText").value == hello) {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Hi'; }
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
if (SearchText.value === hi) { document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Hi'; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main">
<div id="console"> </div>
<p>Code: <input type="text" id="code"></p>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#code").keyup(function() {
            if (this.value == "Hello") {
                $("#console").css("display", "block");
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += 'Type Help for more instructions';
            }
            if (this.value == "Help") {
                $("#console").css("display", "block");
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += '<BR>Type Help again for more instructions';
            }
            if (this.value == "Hello") {
                $("#console").css("display", "block");
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = 'Type Help for more instructions';
            }
            if (this.value == "Hello") {
                $("#console").css("display", "block");
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = 'Type Help for more instructions';
            }
            if (this.value == "Hello") {
                $("#console").css("display", "block");
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = 'Type Help for more instructions';
            }
            if (this.value == "Hello") {
                $("#console").css("display", "block");
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = 'Type Help for more instructions';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now another question is 
how can i make that 
if i write "information Hello"  that is still commands its action?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do this, but

**This should work**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">

            <p id="result"></p>

            <textarea cols="40" id="SearchText" rows="1"></textarea>

            <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Submit!</button>

        </div>
        <script>
           function myFunction() {
            var result = document.getElementById("searchText").value;

            if (result == 'hi') {
                document.getElementById("result").innerText = 'Hi';
            }    
            else{
                console.log(result);
            }

       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However other workarounds are you can use console.log or alert if you are doing some error checking

Comment: You can also compare with a string dynamically instead of using a static string but the above answer is working code of what you provided me

Comment: Thanks . i couldse the console.log(result); over there,, didnt knew that before

Comment: Is this the answer, you were looking for

Comment: yes this was also an answer i was looking for...
i wrote another problem down here 
\.|./
.\|/